# Reduce the win7 partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I'm absolute beginner in the Ubuntu universe (but I like it!). I installed Ubuntu a week ago in a Hp laptop with win7. I have a little (tiny) knowledge about programming, but the technic-languages instructions are hard for me. During the installation I followed some youtube tutorials and the partition to Ubuntu is of 15GB. But in this week (I feel) I've improved some skills. I've resolved small issues and I want to take the step to Ubuntu, but my mom use sometimes my laptop and she only use windows.

So, I want give more space to Ubuntu and leave a modest partition to win7 (for occasional use of my mom) .  How can I do that? Moreover, Can I do that without loose my  current Ubuntu configuration, files, apps...?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

that is great to hear that you love the new install of Ubuntu. I must admit, that I loved it too and have not looked back at all. The more you play with it, the more you will love it and the more you will realise you don't like the bigger OS's trying to rule the world. Sorry that is my little rant over lol.

You can reduce the size, but when I looked into it, it was a bit of a game. Have a look at this link, it may help you and good luck.

As the Ubuntu OS is only a week old, you could back up your user folder and then install it again. This time giving the Ubuntu partition the size you require.

[Reduce partition size](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291888/can-i-adjust-reduce-my-partition-size-for-ubuntu)

Comment: Hi! I made it! thanks a lot! Now I never go back to win7 again. Everyday that I used Ubuntu comes with a lot of knowledge and support I appreciate that, thanks again. Quickly,I realized that Ubuntu is lighter, stabler and faster than win7! But today, I realized that Ubuntu is also more compatible with my ideals of society, justice and utopy. I'm glad to be here! & I will be here a lot!

Comment: I am glad to hear that you have done it and no worries, glad to help. I totally agree with you about Ubuntu and I never use Windows at home now. Everything that I need and want is in Ubuntu, so never have the need to go into Windows. I only use it for work. Every program that I need has as excellent Ubuntu alternative. There is Wine, but I have never used it. Glad that you are liking it and all the best finding out more

Comment: Can I ask you to rate the answer, cheers